# How to prevent OpenTK.GameWindow from closing

Tags: c#, opentk

I have a game I've written in OpenTK but am looking for a way to add a handler to the close button of the game window without actually closing the game (e.g. invoking a "do you want to save before you quit?" sort of dialog). I can't seem to find any event handler or documentation that accomplishes this.

Comment: Do you mean the close button of the GameWindow?

Comment: Yes. (edited original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`OnClosing` method](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_game_window.html#ac2bfae65b7874a59517461c72ce66663) and show your message box there.  If the user does not want to close, you can use `e.Cancel = true`, which will stop the form from closing:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // ... show message box
   if (/* wants to save*/)
   {
       // Cancel closing, the player does not want to exist
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
   base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: Woohoo! My problem was I was not overriding the GameWindow class and just creating an instance of it directly and so I overlooked the protected members. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah OpenTK documentation isn't exactly the best IMHO.